# How to make a VirtualTreeView's Node allow TMemo like multiline keyboard input instead of the TEdit like default behavior?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am modifying the MultilineDemo that comes with VirtualTreeView's git folder (Virtual-TreeView-master\Demos\Advanced). I have just removed the multiline 'display' code and added code to the VST's onClick handler to make the clicked node editable.

I want to enter multiline text into a node like TMemo but, the enter or shift+enter key presses finish the editing. See the image below. I couldn't find a keypress event for a node in VST property panel for modifying the default behavior. My goal is to have a tree like control with nodes capable of multiline input

I don't think I have to post any code from my current application.

[image: Default TEdit like behavior of a node in Virtual Tree View]

Comment: You need to implement your own `IVTEditLink` editor, create a memo control and handle its key events. See Demos/Advanced/Editors.pas unit for `vtMemo` type of values. It does certainly what you want (you would have to modify the `EditKeyDown` method for that shift key handling, but the principle can be read from there). If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, Victoria, you can post this comment as an answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Done ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement your own `IVTEditLink` editor, create a memo control and handle its key down event. See the [/Demos/Advanced/Editors.pas](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/blob/master/Demos/Advanced/Editors.pas) unit for `vtMemo` type of values. It does almost what you want. It shows how to create a memo control as a node editor and how to handle the editor's control key down event (in this case the `EditKeyDown` method).